# My write-to folder keeps emptying

Tags: php, ajax, fopen

I am trying to save tokens to a php file using this code, but after 2kb the file mysteriously empties and I lose all the data. Why does this happen? how do I prevent it?

```
   $fh = fopen('token.txt', 'a+');
    fwrite($fh, $access_token . "\n");
    fclose($fh);
```

Comment: That's mysterious indeed. It's unlikely that this is a PHP issue, but rather something that happens in the OS. If you write the file manually, does it still disappear? Also, what does `fwrite()` return? And do you see the file there? Does it disappear only when writing to it, or without accessing it in any way? If you write more than 2K at once, is the file still there, or not created at all?

Comment: i filled it with junk and it did empty

Comment: it emptied when the next entry was dumped. having >2kb won't empty the file but if you do a fwrite to a folder with >2kb it empties everything and starts over until it hits >2kb again.

Comment: So if the folder is empty and you create a 4 KB file by hand in it (with a text editor, not from PHP), it doesn't appear at all? Or does it appear temporarily, then disappears after a short while? Does this happen in any other folder?

Comment: The content in the folder will disappear if a new entry is written to it. having a 4kb file won't empty it, unless you write to it.

Comment: windows 7.0 windows 7 pc

Comment: If this is happening to files that you write yourself, without the use PHP, then you're more likely to find an answer on http://serverfault.com.

Comment: @DorothyPrice: You need to add more information. Rewrite the script so that it one go it reproduces the behavior you describe (e.g. perform the operation X times). This should also clarify the contents for `$access_token` and will allow others to reproduce. Next to the new code, add the exact PHP version and your Operating System to the question (this does not belong inside comments). See as well http://sscce.org/

Comment: Can you please configure your php file with the following to check if there's errors : error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', On);

Answer (score 0):

This token data you speak of, where does it originate from? It doesn't appear that you are appending to the file more so than you are just writing and over writing (I could be wrong), as I don't write to files often. Anyway If this data is being accumulated in something like a session or cookie or a get variable or something to the extent there of before off shooting into the text files you have, that could be some of the issue there. As I know in most cases sessions, cookies, and gets, have a limit, where after said limit is reach they break in one shape form or another. So if thats the case, maybe if your session, cookie, get is too large, the operation to do something with it is treating it as null, invalid, empty, whatever the case, then putting that equivalant into the file your writing to..

Unfortunately without giving more context to your overall script, where are these tokens are generated from to whatever runs, occurs or keeps reoccuring to these tokens to make them larger and larger. Its hard to give a really good answer that maybe of any assistance to you. Based on the code you have above I see no real limits exactly

Also, this could be a windows issue (permissions or otherwise), or a server configuration issue, or a php configuration issue, a lot of different variables tie into this problem, more so as it sounds like its a self hosted development stack on your own machine.

So all in all the more information you can give us, the better we are at helping :-)